# getting errors when trying to install matplotlib and numpy using pip

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have python version 3.3. I did install pip and now trying to install matplotlib and numpy.

```
pip install matplotlib
pip install numpy
```

I get these errors:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 191, in customize_compiler

    _osx_support.customize_compiler(_config_vars)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/_osx_support.py", line 418, in customize_compiler

    _find_appropriate_compiler(_config_vars)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/_osx_support.py", line 191, in _find_appropriate_compiler

    "Cannot locate working compiler")

SystemError: Cannot locate working compiler

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /private/var/folders/fz/4bjb8_8x4rs_8r97vrh92_mh0000gn/T/pip_build_ayseburcuozdal...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/fz/4bjb8_8x4rs_8r97vrh92_mh0000gn/T/pip_build_ayseburcuozdal/numpy
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip-1.5-py3.3.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip-1.5-py3.3.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 270, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip-1.5-py3.3.egg/pip/req.py", line 1206, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip-1.5-py3.3.egg/pip/req.py", line 312, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip-1.5-py3.3.egg/pip/util.py", line 696, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
```

Comment: Do you have a compiler such a gcc installed on your system?

Comment: You need a C compiler to build python extensions written in C.  `pip` essentially just grabs a source tarball and tries to build it.  For the most part, it doesn't deal with pre-built binaries.  It looks like you're on OSX. If so, you'll need to install XCode (or a stripped-down equivalent).  Alternately, you can use pre-built binaries to install matplotlib, numpy, etc (just make sure they're built against the same python executable that you're using).  Another option is python distributions such as Anaconda, Canopy, etc.

Comment: @Joe Kington, I downloaded xcode and installed it. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Numpy`  requires a C compiler in order to be installed. This error message suggests to me that you do not have a C compiler installed or that `pip` can't find it.

Alternatively you might be able to source the binaries for `numpy` if you do not have a compiler available to you. See the `numpy` website for more installation information: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/install.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple 
export CC=gcc
fixed my problem.
(OSX with Xcode installed but same error)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me (OSX 10.8.5)

install Xcode (from App store)

start Xcode

in its preferences, download,   choose Command Line Tools wait for it to install

you can quit Xcode

in terminal :

CC=gcc

pip3 install matplotlib

pip3 install six

I run python 3.4 recently downloaded
I had to get six on top of matplotlib to get pyplot to run properly